# How to import data from one sheet to "only one cell" in another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

Using google sheets, I am able to transfer data from one sheet to another sheet using

> =IMPORTRANGE

but IMPORTRANGE creates more cells depending on how many cells you are copying over. I need to copy all data from sheet1 into only one cell of sheet 2. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this for Google Sheets, or Excel?

Comment: @BruceWayne: Excel hasn't a IMPORTRANGE built-in function, Google Sheets has it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you authorize the access to the external spreadsheet, try

```
=JOIN(CHAR(10),QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IMPORTRANGE(spreadsheet_key,reference_string)),,2E6))
```

If the source data is

```
+---+----+----+
|   | A  | B  |
+---+----+----+
| 1 | A1 | B1 |
| 2 | A2 | B2 |
+---+----+----+
```

the result will be

```
+---+---------+
|   |   A     |
+---+---------+
| 1 | A1 B1   |
|   | A2 B2   |
+---+---------+
```

Comment: You ROck! Thanks!